# IOS: recognize a swipe gesture

Tags: ios, touch, uigesturerecognizer

In my app I have this code:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{

    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
        return YES;
    }

    else return NO;
}
```

In this I control if my touch is inside a scrollView or not but now I want to check if the touch is a simple touch or is a swipe gesture, is there a way to detect it?
thanks

Comment: Just add a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to your view and whenever the action used in the creation of the recognizer is executed then it's a swipe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method you written above is UIGestureRecognizerDelegate. This is a delegate method will get called when particular gesture on which you put an observer, gets detected.

In order to identify swipe gesture, you have to add Gesture recognizer to View on which you want to detect as below:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
[recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release];
```

You can get gesture detection in method **handleSwipeForm:**

If you want to get the above delegate to get called then also add this line,

```
recognizer.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to detect swipe gestures (you can set the swipe direction:  `UISwipeGestureRecognizer.direction`)

And a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to detect taps (`UITapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired` sets the required number of taps to trigger the recognizer (e. g. for double-taps)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UISwipeGestureRecognizer in order to detect swipe gestures .

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGest= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeRecognizer:)];
[swipeGest setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:swipeGest];
swipeGest.delegate = self;
```

setDirection is used to set the swipe detect direction.

```
- (void)SwipeRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
}
```

Here we will be writing the function to do after detecting the swipe gesture.